# MySQL stored procedure BEGIN / END statements throwing errors

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a stored procedure and having real issues debugging.

I've tried cutting everything out to try and track down the issue, and even down to this I'm getting errors:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_transpose_tickets;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_transpose_tickets ()
BEGIN
select 1;
END
```

errors are:

```
> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 2
> 
> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'END' at line 1
```

This is on my local machine, under root user so all privileges are granted and I am running mySQL 5.5.20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define the delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_transpose_tickets $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_transpose_tickets ()
BEGIN
    select 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using Dbeaver. All I need to do was select my query from the beginning to the end and run the query. If I put my cursor only in the beginning without selecting all the code the same error was shown for me.